# Stanford CoreNLP dependencies parser

Tags: stanford-nlp

I got the following values from Stanford CoreNPL basic dependencies parser:

```
acl:relcl
compound:prt
```

I cannot find explanation what they mean neither [here](http://universaldependencies.org/docs/u/dep/index.html) nor [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf).

Could somebody direct me to the exhaustive list of dependencies tags? I am actually looking for something in simple machine readable format.